# Creating a url slug / route for login page using Vue.js and/or AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, vuejs2, aws-lambda, vue-component

I am building my first Vue.js app with AWS Lambda and have a bucket set up in S3 for my pages.  I have a login.html page set up but want the route to be:

```
https://example.com/login
```

to route to my html login page.  I want the browser to still say /login without the extension too.

How is this done?

Thanks I am learning Vue and Lambda for the first time.

Comment: you can use api gateway and create the route /login which map to this lambda with ts integration response....

Comment: Is there an example of this? I still need to understand it better.